# Public Amazon EC2 AMIs with R pre-installed

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, cloud

I know about the 2 opendata [AMI](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Amazon_Machine_Image)s, but I was wondering if there are other, publicly available AMIs that come with R pre-installed?  It would be wonderful if they came with the server version of R studio too.

Comment: I've considered building this myself but have not made the time to do it. I've also been pestering AMZN to donate an EC2 instance for use as a CRAN mirror

Comment: @JD Long: Keep pestering them! And please post here when you get around to building a public R AMI.  I suggest including RStudio when you do.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm maintaining AMIs specifically for RStudio Server which have R on.  Details are at http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 9):

The [Bioconductor AMI](http://bioconductor.org/help/bioconductor-cloud-ami/) includes R (and Rstudio). What where the two AMIs you know of?

Comment: Search for 'opendata' in the AMI name. http://opendatagroup.com/2009/11/15/analytics-on-demand/

Comment: @DWin The "opendata" ami still shows up on amazon, but now I can't find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 7):

I researched this question further and found an EC2 AMI with R pre-installed. I also figured out how to get RStudio working on it. The instructions are documented [here](http://community.mis.temple.edu/stevenljohnson/2011/03/12/rstudio-and-amazon-web-services-ec2/).

Comment: Zach, I double checked the link and it works fine. Nonetheless, the information there is probably now out of date as Amazon AMIs do change often.

Answer (score 4):

Here are [some directions I found to setup R and RStudio on amazon EC2](http://inundata.org/2011/03/30/r-ec2-rstudio-server/).